# ObjectListView group by button click

Tags: c#, grouping, objectlistview, columnsorting

I want to group my ObjectListView but I can only group it when I click on the specific column, but I want to group the list when I click on a button. How can I change that? And I have no event for a column click or something...
I´m using `this.objectListView1.ShowGroups = true;` and I changed the value `Groupable`in the objectlistview settings to `true`.

This is how it looks like when I click on the button:

[image: screenshot1]

and this is how it looks like when I click on the specific column:

[image: screenshot2]

And I don't know why but when I click it also the color of the changes to blue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to group the list when i click on a button.

```
objectListView.BuildGroups(myOlvColumn, SortOrder.Ascending);
```

Where `myOlvColumn` is the Column you want to create groups for. That should do it.

Comment: Thank you dude. You are the OLV Pro!